# using lists to return a list of common letters in two names using Python

Tags: python

I'm need to use lists to find letters that are in both a first name and a last name. I'm not allowed to use sets. This is what I have so far, but I'm slightly stuck. I know that I need to somehow use the `in` operator to find out what characters are in the first and last name. And then add the common characters to the blank list `common`. But I need help with the syntax.

```
def firstAndLast(first,last):
    common = []
    if first in last:
        print first


first = list(raw_input("Enter first name: "))
last = list(raw_input("Enter last name: "))

firstAndLast(first, last)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def firstAndLast(firstName, lastName):
    common = set(firstName) & set(lastName)
    print list(common)
```

Comment: "I'm not allowed to use sets."

Comment: I can't use sets. But I solved my own problem thanks anyways.

Comment: I write these things because I object to such assignments on principle. Sorry you're being put through it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over the letters in first:

```
for letter in first:
    if letter in last:
        print letter
```

But you might want to think about duplicate letters (e.g. for "Stephen" and "Colbert" the "e" will be printed twice), and capitalization (e.g. in "Samuel" and "Adams", the "S" will not match the "s").

Answer (score -1):

```
def common_name(first,last):
    common_char=[]

    for i in first:
        if i in last:
            common_char.append(i)

        else:
            pass
    print(common_char)

common_name("prince","pate")
```

Comment: I suspect this will print repeated letters more than once.  For example, what is the output with `common_name("persephone", "pate")`?